# Does logrotate remove .gz files? That is, does logrotate with a * path rotate an existing .gz file?

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, logrotate, glob

// , The question's a bit ambiguous.

Here is the scenario:

I have logs with the following three extensions, but my current rule only applies to *.log files:

```
.1
.log
.txt
```

Plus, because Tomcat is rotating logs, I have the following:

```
.gz
```

***I want to rotate all of these files, but I don't want to end up with any .gz.gz files. How do I do this?***

## Logrotate Rule for Tomcat

Currently, I have the following rule for the Tomcat logs:

```
% sudo cat /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
# THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY DISTRIBUTED BY PUPPET.  ANY CHANGES WILL BE
# OVERWRITTEN.

/opt/apache-tomcat_1/logs/*.log {
  compress
  daily
  delaycompress
  maxage 60
  maxsize 500M
  minsize 1k
  rotate 20
  size 100k
}
```

To try to solve this, I could change the `/opt/apache-tomcat_1/logs/*.log` path to something like `/opt/apache-tomcat_1/logs/*`, but I wonder if that would re-compress or process the `.gz` files in the same way as the `.log` and `.txt` files.

Does `logrotate` have some way of knowing to leave existing `.gz` files well enough alone?

## Other Files

The last time the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` got an update was about 12 days ago:

```
% sudo ls -lanh /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
-r-xr-xr-x 1 0 0 313 Jun 29 21:48 /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Its contents are as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY DISTRIBUTED BY PUPPET.  ANY CHANGES WILL BE
# OVERWRITTEN.

OUTPUT=$(/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf 2>&1)
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
fi
exit $EXITVALUE
```

And, in case it's relevant:

```
% cat /etc/logrotate.conf
# THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY DISTRIBUTED BY PUPPET.
# ANY CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN.

create
weekly
rotate 4

# configurable file rotations
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

I did a [quick search online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=does%20logrotate%20rotate%20an%20existing%20.gz%20file) for this, and [found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593910/what-exactly-does-logrotate-do-to-apache-log-files-apache-2-4-ubuntu-14-04) [some](https://linuxconfig.org/setting-up-logrotate-on-redhat-linux) [results](https://serverfault.com/questions/377031/logrotate-does-not-remove-old-logs). The askubuntu.com answer was closest, but I am still not sure whether `logrotate` will "rotate" `.gz` files created by another service, like Tomcat.

Nothing in those results answers this specific question about pre-existing .gz files created by another service (e.g. Tomcat) when `*` globbing is used in the logrotate path.

Right now I'm simply solving this with multiple paths/rules: https://v.gd/yNfAAu

But I'm curious. What script behavior intelligently makes `logrotate` ignore the existing `.gz` files, or process them differently, while still removing those that are sufficiently old or large? Does Logrotate have a way to do this already?

Comment: // , Reading over this, now, it looks like it might be a better fit for serverfault.com. Feel free to migrate as needed, or suggest edits.

Comment: Could be posted to askubuntu.com also

Comment: What's with the // ,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "man logrotate"

You can use the variable "tabooext" to specify file extensions that you wish logrotate to ignore.